# Stretch a Grid inside a ListView in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a `Grid` inside a `ListView`. If I place the `Grid` *outside* of the `ListView`, it correctly stretches to fill the screen. If I place it *within* the `ListView`, it does not. Here's my code

```
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListViewItem>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">Title</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Text</TextBlock>
                <Button Grid.Column="1">Pin</Button>
            </Grid>
        </ListViewItem>            
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

How do I get the `Grid` it to stretch and fill the `ListView`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probaby need to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the `ListViewItem` to `Stretch`.

Comment: That did the job. I knew it'd be something simple! Thanks.